# Exception in thread main java.lang.NullPointerException while fetching value from database

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

I just trying to run a problem java program on eclipse, but getting NullPointerException. My code is posted below.Please tell me what I did wrong.

Rect.java

```
package org.spring.model;

public class Rect {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Rect(int rectId, String rectName)
    {
        setId(rectId);
        setName(rectName);
    }


}
```

JdbcDaoImplement.java

```
    package org.spring.dao;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import org.spring.model.Rect;

public class JdbcDaoImplement {

    public Rect getRect(int rectId)
    {
        Connection conn=null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, "system", "abcd");
            PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM RECTANGLE WHERE id=?");
            ps.setInt(1, rectId);

            Rect rect=null;
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()==true)
            {
                rect=new Rect(rectId,rs.getString("name"));
            }
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            return rect;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, JdbcDemo.java

```
package org.spring;

import org.spring.dao.JdbcDaoImplement;
import org.spring.model.Rect;

public class JdbcDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rect rect=new JdbcDaoImplement().getRect(1);
        System.out.println(rect.getName());
    }

}
```

And the stack trace is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.spring.JdbcDemo.main(JdbcDemo.java:10)
```

Comment: If you're going to tell us about an exception, please give the full stack trace.

Comment: Ok I edited and re-posted the question with full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very likely in your main method `rect` is null, and you called `rect.getName()`, then Bang! NPE.

because in your `getRect(int rectId)` method, you handled exception in the method, and then return a `rect`, if there is something going wrong or  `rs.next()` is false, you will return a null `rect` object.

what you could consider to do is, either redesign the `getRect()` method, let it never return null, E.g if no record found, or exception occured, throw exception(s); or in your main method, check the `rect`, make sure it is not null.

Comment: ok I changed the code and re edited the question ...but still getting same error.

Comment: did you debug your codes? e.g. `rs.next()` returns true or false? try debugging first!